# Subtracting two CV_64FC3 matrices and keeping the negative values

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

As far as i know, subtracting two non-float matrices yields expected results but subtracting two CV_64FC3 (and CV_32F for that matter) matrices clips the negative values to 0.0 **and** normalizes the result between 0.0 and 1.0. I know these limitations and read related documentation but still couldn't subtract two matrices.

```
    Mat lowpass1, lowpass2, mask;
    
    mask.convertTo(mask, CV_32F);
    lowpass1.convertTo(lowpass1, CV_32F);
    lowpass2.convertTo(lowpass2, CV_32F);           
    
    // all other variables (high_b1, high_a0 etc.) are double 
    // and in the range of -1.0 to 1.0 but never 0.0
    // frame and prev_frame are CV_32F matrices

    lowpass1 = (-high_b1 * lowpass1 + high_a0 * frame + high_a1 * prev_frame) / high_b0;
    lowpass2 = (-low_b1 * lowpass2 + low_a0 * frame + low_a1 * prev_frame) / low_b0;

    mask = lowpass1 - lowpass2
```

Altough the lowpass1 and lowpass2 contains non zero positive values, the subtraction  always gives 0. I'm assuming it's clipping and/or rounding up to the nearest integer.

```
    mask = lowpass2 - lowpass1
```

This also gives the exact same result as mentioned above.

Working minimal example;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::list;
using std::vector;
using cv::Mat;

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap("small.mp4");
    const int level = 2;
    vector<Mat> *data = new vector<Mat>;
    vector<vector<Mat>> pyramid;
    pyramid.resize(level);
    Mat frame;

    while (true) {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
            break;
        frame.convertTo(frame, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0f);
        data->push_back(frame.clone());

        Mat current = frame.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            Mat down, up;
            if (i == (level - 1)) {
                pyramid[i].push_back(current);
                break;
            }
            cv::pyrDown(current, down);
            cv::pyrUp(down, up, current.size());
            pyramid[i].push_back(current - up);
            current = down;
        }
    }

    double low_a0 = 0.04979798;
    double low_a1 = 0.04979798;
    double low_b0 = 1;
    double low_b1 = -0.90040404;
    double high_a0 = 0.13672874;
    double high_a1 = 0.13672874;
    double high_b0 = 1;
    double high_b1 = -0.72654253;
    
    vector<vector<Mat>> filtered;
    filtered.resize(level);

    for (int i = 1; i < pyramid.size(); i++) {
        Mat lowpass1 = pyramid[i][0], lowpass2 = pyramid[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < pyramid[i].size(); j++) {       
            lowpass1 = (-high_b1 * lowpass1 + high_a0 * pyramid[i][j] + high_a1 * pyramid[i][j-1]) / high_b0;
            lowpass2 = (-low_b1 * lowpass2 + low_a0 * pyramid[i][j] + low_a1 * pyramid[i][j - 1]) / low_b0;

            filtered[i].push_back(lowpass1 - lowpass2);
        }
    }

}
```

The source video; http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

Comment: what are the types of all the high low frame prev_frame variables? OpenCV operators can easily overwrite the output variable by a matrix of another type, if the original type or size doesnt fit. As a quick hack you could do `lowpass1.convertTo(lowpass1, CV_32F);
    lowpass2.convertTo(lowpass2, CV_32F);` AFTER the computation of lowpass1 and lowpass2

Comment: The problem may that you don't actually convert the `lowpass1` or `lowpass2` -- you have `lowpass1.convertTo(filtre, CV_32F);` and same thing for `lowpass2`.... so you write the converted array to some other matrix you don't use in later statements.

Comment: how are you testing the values of the mask? `imshow` will scale and clip the values for rendering. `imwrite` wont work well either, because image types typucally dont know negative values. You might have to test in a different way. If you want to save and load 32F or 64F matrices (or any other non-image-type) you can use a Serializer function (sorry, cant remember the name atm) that saves matrices as strings in some kind of xml file.

Comment: @DanMašek, made a mistake while translating from my native language, in the original code it is `lowpass1.convertTo(lowpass1, CV_32F);`, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Micka, I'm both using imshow and outputting the values to a txt file. Tried the conversion hack after the computation but got the same result. lowpass1 and lowpass2 does work though, both in imshow and in a txt file.

Comment: Then there's nothing obvious from the snippet you've shown. Try to create a [MCVE] -- a self contained program, working with small matrices that you can initialize with constant values, which will reproduce the problem you've got. | It seemed odd that that would be the case, (I've used float mats before and didn't run into such issue), and i just verified that it's not happening in a short test program...

Comment: @DanMašek, added the relevant part of the code. I'm not entirely sure how to write a MRE for this instance since I'm not 100% sure where the problem might lie.

Comment: I understand. The edit you made was useful. | The first step I would take is to get rid of anything unnecessary -- for example `data` is only written to, so get rid of that. | The next thing I'd ask myself would be whether i need the whole video to reproduce this, or whether just the first frame is enough. If that was the case, i'd reduce the code to just use a single PNG file holding the first frame, and thus reduce the complexity further. | And so on, this is sort of detective work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this part;

```
lowpass1 = (-high_b1 * lowpass1 + high_a0 * pyramid[i][j] + high_a1 * pyramid[i][j-1]) / high_b0;
lowpass2 = (-low_b1 * lowpass2 + low_a0 * pyramid[i][j] + low_a1 * pyramid[i][j - 1]) / low_b0;
```

Since lowpass1 and lowpass2 are used in the formula and the left hand side of the code, it messed up something but I'm not sure what it did exactly. After changing it to this;

```
Mat lowpass1_, lowpass2_;
lowpass1_ = (high_b1 * lowpass1 + high_a0 * pyramid[i][j] + high_a1 * pyramid[i][j - 1]);
lowpass2_ = (low_b1 * lowpass2 + low_a0 * pyramid[i][j] + low_a1 * pyramid[i][j - 1]);
```

the calculations were correct and didn't clip to zero etc. Thanks for all the replies.